# How to initialize std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T>[]>?

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

My class has this member:

```
static std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>[]> changestatecommands;
```

and I cannot find the correct way to initialize this. I want the array to be initialized, but the elements uninitialized, so I can at any time write something like:

```
changestatecommands[i] = std::make_unique<ICommand>();
```

It does not matter if the array is initialized immediately at the declaration, or later in runtime. Optimally, I would like to know how to do both.

Comment: Why not just a simple vector of pointers, as in `std::vector<ICommand*>` (or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>>` if you want ownership semantics).

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>>`?

Comment: Read that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array/16711846  It has to be last resort solution and those usually smell bad.

Comment: @t.niese no actually not. I'm just learning about smart pointers, so I guess I got caught up in it and use the m for everything. Would there be any benefits to using a unique_ptr as I have, or is it the exact same thing?

Comment: I think there are only significant disadvantages to use `unique_ptr[]` as you have.

Comment: It is more about avoiding c style array (`std::unique_ptr<ICommand>[]`),  and using an std container instead.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377360/proper-way-to-create-unique-ptr-that-holds-an-allocated-array

Comment: Whenever you have a question about C++, one of the first place to look is **CPP reference**. Look case (2) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to initialize `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>[]>`?

Like this

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>[]> changestatecommands{
    new std::unique_ptr<ICommand>[10]{nullptr}
};

// or using a type alias
using UPtrICommand = std::unique_ptr<ICommand>;
std::unique_ptr<UPtrICommand[]> changestatecommands{ new UPtrICommand[10]{nullptr} };

//or like @t.niese mentioned
using UPtrICommand = std::unique_ptr<ICommand>;
auto changestatecommands{ std::make_unique<UPtrICommand[]>(10) };
```

---

However, as others mentioned, think about the alternatives, such as

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>>  // credits  @t.niese
```

before coming into the above conclusion.

Comment: I would use `std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>[]>(10)` instead, in combination with `auto`: `auto changestatecommands = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>[]>(10)`

Comment: @t.niese Also possible. Let me add it to the answer.