# Ways to initialize RAII

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm curious, what is the difference between this:

```
std::unique_ptr<char> ptr = std::unique_ptr<char>(new char[1000]);
```

and this:

```
std::unique_ptr<char> ptr(new char[1000]);
```

Also, this is unrelated, but how can I use `make_unique` for an array without initializing the values?

Comment: Neither is legal, ITYM `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`

Comment: It is an array to use `std::unique_ptr<char>` to hold a `char` array. Use `std::vector<char>` or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`. Please read [Proper way to create unique_ptr that holds an allocated array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377360/proper-way-to-create-unique-ptr-that-holds-an-allocated-array).

Comment: @john but it compiles and works.

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question was what is the difference between init an object like this: `Object obj(params)` and this: `Object obj = Object(params)`

Comment: C++20 introduces `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` which default initializes the object. I believe for `char[]` this would mean not initializing its elements.

Comment: @ManUser123 So you not specifically interested in unique_ptr?

Comment: @john No. I'm just curious at the differences between those 2 init methods

Comment: @Suthiro It compiles and it works does not guarantee that it is correct.

Comment: @Suthiro Compiling and looking like it works does not make it correct. This version is equivalent to using `delete` instead of `delete[]` for an array. It is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @ManUser123 Probably should have picked a made up type to illustrate the question then.

Comment: @john Yeah. Now I have to wait 90 minutes :(

Comment: @ManUser123 Then is the last sentence of your question entirely unrelated to the rest of the question?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are right, now I see.

Comment: @ManUser123 I'm sure this has been asked before, I see if I can find a duplicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, the last sentence was unrelated. My bad.

Comment: @ManUser123 Found a reasonable duplicate for part 1.

Comment: @john Thanks! I'll check it out