# Proper syntax for defining a unique_ptr array of class objects with a constructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I want an array of class objects with `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass[]> arr(new MyClass[n]);
```

`MyClass` has no default constructor (and in my case is not supposed to have), so I have to put it explicitly here. I cannot find out how to do it so it is syntactically correct. What is the correct way to write a `unique_ptr` array of class objects with explicit initialisation?

**Clarification**

I have a non-default constuctor for `MyClass`, like this:

```
MyClass instance(arguments);
```

Apart from member initialisations, there are also some calculations in the constructor. I want to create a `unique_ptr` array of `MyClass` instances and call the constructor for each of the instances. I cannot do that later since `MyClass` has no default constructor. Can I put `(arguments)` somewhere in `std::unique_ptr<MyClass[]> arr(new MyClass[n])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to create unique\_ptr that holds an allocated array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377360/proper-way-to-create-unique-ptr-that-holds-an-allocated-array)

Comment: @PepijnKramer It is about an array with explicit initialisation of an instance of a class, not just a plain allocated array

Comment: You will have to either use pointers in such an array, or allocate required space by manipulating bytes (`char`) and then assign initialized values. However before you do that, why don't you just use `std::vector`?

Comment: @RichardCritten where do I put arguments for the constructor?

Comment: You could also simply derive from `std::array<MyClass, N>` and provide a constructor. Then use a `unique_ptr` to that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below is based on a previous version of the question, in which the array size appeared to be a compile-time constant. If the size of the created array is not a compile-time constant, then it is impossible to pass arguments to the constructors of the elements. In that case `std::vector` is probably a better choice than array-`std::unique_ptr`.

---

It works the same as always for arrays, using aggregate initialization:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass[]> arr(new MyClass[]{
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}});
```

where `...` are replaced by the argument lists for the constructors of the five elements.

Or if you cannot use list-initialization for the elements, e.g. because that would unintentionally use a `std::initializer_list` constructor:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass[]> arr(new MyClass[]{
    MyClass(...),
    MyClass(...),
    MyClass(...),
    MyClass(...),
    MyClass(...)});
```

`std::make_unique` would usually be preferred for creating `std::unique_ptr`s, but there is at the moment no overload which allows passing arguments to the constructors of the individual array elements.

---

If you want to pass the same argument list to each element, a simple solution given that the type is copy-constructible would be to declare one instance and then copy-construct the elements from this instance:

```
MyClass instance(arguments);
std::unique_ptr<MyClass[]> arr(new MyClass[]{instance, instance, instance, instance, instance);
```

Otherwise you could write a template function that expands these repeated items for you. (Might add example later.)

Comment: Can I call my constructor here somehow? If creating a single instance, it looks like `MyClass instance(arguments)`. Apart from initialising members, the constructor also has some calculations under the hood, which should also be done

Comment: @Kaiyakha Yes, you replace `...` with `arguments`. If you must use paranthesized initialization instead of list-initialization with braces, you can replace `{...}` with `MyClass(arguments)` as well.

Comment: Is there any way to have one `(arguments)` for all elements of the array?

Comment: the amount of instances is not known at compile time, sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: @Kaiyakha Then what you are trying to do is impossible. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I think it would work with a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass, customDeleter>` with the customDeleter calling `delete[]`

Comment: @Sebastian That doesn't solve the problem that you can't initialize a `new`ed array's elements with constructor arguments if the size of the array is unknown at compile time. You would need to placement-new each element individually, which then would require a destructor that properly destructs each element. At this point it would get complicated enough that I wouldn't try to avoid `std::vector` without a very good reason.

Comment: @user17732522 I agree that it would get complicated, and I also would use `std::vector` in 99.9% of those cases anyway instead of a C array. Especially because we do not need a `unique_ptr` with `vector` (the functionality is built in), so we do not even save an indirection. The `vector` can be constructed with exactly the intended size.